# Wordpress site is showing 404 error for pages - but with my IPB forum

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ipb, invision-power-board

I have a WordPress website, running at the root of my website. And an invision install running on the `directory /forums/`

I'm using a code to show a welcome `$USER$` if logged into IPB, now recently without any change to my knowledge, possibly an update to IPB, every WordPress `page/post` kicks out a `404 error`. But not a 404 in WordPress, a 404 under the forums?

You can see this here:

http://www.tfuhq.com/ - WordPress home page (WORKS)

http://www.tfuhq.com/autobots/ - WordPress internal page (404)

http://www.tfuhq.com/forums/ - FORUMS (WORKS)

This is the htaccess for the wordpress install:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is htaccess for the forums:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forums/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /forums/public/404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forums/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you get into the WordPress admin?  Sometimes re-saving the permalinks (under Settings .. Permalinks from memory) will fix a strange 404 problem.

Comment: Hello @Hobo just tried this but no luck, i can access the wordpress admin just fine

Comment: I have the same issue. It lets me get to the home page but will not let me access inner pages. When I try to visit them, chrome developer tools shows the pages as directories, not pages.

Comment: Provide a detailed rewrite log for buggy requests. Exclude `/forum/` from the 1st ruleset by adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/`

Comment: try to delete the .htacces and the wp-config.php, re-execute the wp install script and insert the DB info, it will generate the files again and reconnect with the DB

Comment: Do your URLs end with a "/" ? If not, try to add a slash and see if they are working then.